# Can I move (the view) on a 2-D scale (Only up and down)?

Tags: 3d-view

I want to move my camera (not the Blender camera) only up and down. If I zoom in on a section, the other section of the project disappears (I am terrible at explaining)

I also can't just move the entire picture because I'm using a background image as reference.

Comment: The question is not really clear. Maybe Ctrl+8 and Ctrl+2 (Numpad) ? Shift+middle mouse button ?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while pressing the middle mouse button (or scroll wheel) and move the mouse to re-position the window.

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and roll the scroll wheel to move the view up and down.

Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> and roll the scroll wheel to move the view left or right

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to re-center the camera view window.